# Why have I not received the specialist badge?

Tags: support, badges, specialist-badge

I now have > 400 upvotes within jQuery tagged questions (see below images) but have not received the badge as yet. I passed the 400 mark a good few hours ago. Can anybody shed any light on this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wait a few more hours?

Comment: Is it time based? e.g does the system have to go through a recalc job in order to issue these badges? Thats why I am asking the question and vague answers like that really do not answer anything do they!

Comment: Yah, sometimes, things take some time to get processed.  Wait a day and see what happens.

Comment: (replied to comment)

Comment: You've now been badged.

Comment: I noticed, time was the key.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Different badges run on different cycles. Some every few minutes, some daily.

I used to have access to the server logs that showed this, but Jeff took my shiny toys away ;-( Meaning: I can't check what the cycle is for this specific badge.

So as has been suggested; wait a day...

Comment: Cheers Mark. Thanks for the confirmation. Why did he retract your toys?

Comment: I think it was a few server-specific ones that people outside the SO dev team had no real **need** to use. Most of the tools remain ;-p

Comment: Retraction of toys sounds painful. I hope you aren't walking funny.

Comment: Calculated daily at 5PM UTC