# Confusion over total upvotes used in tag-based badges calculation

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

The legend for the tag-based badges page states that "*you'll have to earn 1000 up votes in non-community wiki questions to achieve this [gold] badge*."

Which up votes figure is used in the calculation though? According to the Info tab, I was up voted 1018 times on non community-wiki answers within the ruby-on-rails tag. Yet according to the Stats tab I have an all-time score of 991. Should I have my gold badge or not? Does the difference of 27 occur because the all-time score includes down votes?

Comment: Another inquiry on the subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59466/somehow-i-dont-get-badges. As far as the difference of 26, the tag stats score is [a bit more complicated than just upvotes - downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-tag-stats-page-calculated/52792#52792). It's specifically the sum of (upvotes-downvotes) on all non-CW posts where upvotes > downvotes.

Comment: Thanks Grace. Two more characters to go before it will accept my comment. Nothing to see here, move along...

Comment: It would be nice to get an official answer on this.

Comment: Bountied you up.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to add a bounty myself actually.

Comment: Well, I can afford it anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the badge now. So the answer is that the badge is awarded according to the total that appears in the Stats tab and not the Info tab.