# Reviewer Badge not awarded

Tags: support, badges, review

A few days ago I actioned over 200 of my over 1000 reviews, but I still haven't received the Reviewer Badge. Am I missing something? Or is there a time delay until it gets awarded?

```
Upvoted 137

Downvoted 1

Edited 8

Commented 3

Voted to Close 0

Flagged 55

Deleted 0

Reviewed 1235
```

I have never been any good at math, but by my calculation that's 204 actioned.

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you sure that Up/Downvotes counts as action?

Comment: According to this it does http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111645/172857

Comment: I does only if the questions stay live. Also edits only count if they are approved. Flags only count if they're "helpful". (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

Comment: Ah right, that might be why, I will action some more and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: @Mat That worked, I must have had a few that had been deleted or flags that had been declined. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have patience. Badges can take anywhere from a few seconds up to a few hours before they actually get awarded to your account. It depends on what badge it is and when you achieved it. For example (for me), the Nice Answer badge tends to get awarded within 15 minutes, while a badge such as Enthusiast (visited 30 consecutive days) can take up to 2 and a half hours to get awarded. Badges are [awarded on cycles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12058) which, aside from the staff, we really don't know much anything about. If you achieved a badge's requirements just after a cycle ran, you'll have to wait the entire cycle for it to check again. As for when the cycles run, we just know they occur, and you will get the badges you deserve eventually.

If you're ever unsure, make sure to check out the [List of All Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258) for specific requirements on each badge, to make sure you're completing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It can take some time to get it rewarded.

In the mean time, you can review some more posts.

**Edit:** I looked at your profile and you already have it.  Happy reviewing!

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have it now, see the comments from @Mat :)