# Electorate Badge Error

Tags: bug, badges, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)
>   [Reviewer Badge not awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122653/reviewer-badge-not-awarded)

So today I looked at my votes count and thought that I met the criteria for the Electorate badge. The criteria are as follows (taken from here [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)):

> - Vote on 600 questions, and have at least 25% of the total number of votes cast be votes on questions
>     Comment votes do not count

Here is an image of my vote count:

[image]

So I have voted on over 600 questions (609) and more then 25% of the total number of votes cast are on questions (212/609 = 34.8%). It's been almost an hour since I passed the 600 question marked and I have still not received the badge. So basically, I'm asking if I have something wrong or if it's just a bug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait for the badge script to run.

Comment: @Mysticial How long does the usually take?

Comment: I don't remember. It'd been a long time since I got it. But the scripts for different badges run at different frequencies depending on how expensive it is.

Comment: @Mysticial Expensive meaning the frequency at which it is attained?

Comment: Expensive as in how hard it is to query. For example "Nice Answer" badges usually come within a few minutes. But "Enlightened" can take several hours.

Comment: @qegal: You are great electorate. And your question voting percentage is not 34.8%. It is (609/821= 74.17%).

Comment: @qegal - Where do you find that vote count that you posted an image of there?

Comment: @Mike - On my own page

Comment: Yay, I'm glad I found this before posting a new question that would have been dup'd to this one. There were a lot of Electorate not-actually-a-bug questions, and they were all "you misread the requirements" except for this one. I definitely didn't misread the requirements; guess I'll just have to wait patiently (I want the "you got a gold badge" hat! :))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not all badges are awarded immediately upon meeting the requirements to receive them. Most badges are given out on a schedule (sort of like a cron job), so it often takes some waiting before you receive a badge.

The last Electorate badge was awarded 11 hours ago to someone else. Try waiting a little longer. Since you've waited almost an hour, you'll probably get yours soon.

If you still don't have it after a day, *then* something is amiss.

Comment: Sure. I'll make sure to mark you as the answer if that's the case. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is one of the badges that just has a low percentage chance of running at some certain interval of time. So there is no *exact* estimate we can give for when it'll be awarded.

Comment: It worked! Sorry for the false alarm. Guess I should be more patient next time.

Comment: @qegal: Congrats!

Comment: This info should probably go into an FAQ, such as [How do badges work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work).